# Iterate variables in SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm writing a function to fade items in, in sequence...

```
.sequenced-images li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.sequenced-images li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.sequenced-images li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sequenced-images li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

I have a lot of items and I don't want to have to manually keep adding a class for the next item.

Can I iterate over the same rule using something like...

```
.sequenced-images li:nth-child(i++) {
  animation-delay: i++s;
}
```

?

Comment: Can't you do this in a loop?

Comment: Take a look here: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`for` loop](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while) and [string interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
@for $i from 2 through 5 {
  .sequenced-images li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: '#{$i - 1}s';
  }
}
```

This will result in:

```
.sequenced-images li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: "1s";
}

.sequenced-images li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: "2s";
}

.sequenced-images li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: "3s";
}

.sequenced-images li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: "4s";
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Does that mean everytime an Item is added I need to update the "2 through 5" or can I use a wildcard so I can add as amny items as I like?

Comment: You're welcome! :) You have to update number in the loop header, I can't think of a wildcard solution.